# c# web api [required] not working for some classes in complex object

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core

I have these classes:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<AnotherClass> anotherClassList { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    [Required]
    public string anotherName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<ThirdClass> third { get; set; }
}

public class ThirdClass
{
    [Required] public string foo3;

    [Required]
    public FourthClass four;
}

public class FourthClass
{
    [Required]
    public string foo4 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string bar4
```

And this controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateModelProperly([FromBody] RequestModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
     return NoContent();
}
```

And only the `[Required]` properties from `RequestModel` and `AnotherClass` is validated by the framework. The two remaining classes are completely ignored (properties just set to `null` if i omit them from the json body).

Is there some limitation by the framework, or what the heck is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the validation module needs getter and setter methods to be able to validate the requirements. After adding `get; set;` methods for the properties, the validation works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Martin's solution below.
My attempts to find a solution were wrong.

**EDIT**

I had misunderstood your problem at first.
This seems to have to do with the validation depth.

Have you tried setting the MvcOptions.MaxValidationDepth Property in your mvc options to null to disable a maximum depth?
I'm not sure it will work but it might.
You set it in your Startup.cs file like so:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options => 
    {
        options.MaxValidationDepth = null;
    })
```

**EDIT**

As far as I can tell you need to add BindRequired to the frombody attribute to actually get it to behave as you expect.
This results in a method that looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateModelProperly([BindRequired, FromBody] RequestModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
     return NoContent();
}
```

as opposed to:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateModelProperly([FromBody] RequestModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
     return NoContent();
}
```

I hope this helps, if I misunderstood anything or if you see mistakes I made please let me know!

Comment: As the 2 of the classes properties are already validated, and the two last are ignored, i doubt it's gonna change much. But i'm gonna give it a shot :). Edit: Nope, doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Ah I can see that I definitely misunderstood your problem!

Comment: I figured it out. The `[Required]` properties needs get and set methods to be able to be validated. I guess the model deserialization is done with reflection or something, and validation is done through getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

With this complicated model, I would recommend to use IValidatableObject or 
FluentValiation

IValidatableObject use:

```
public class AnotherClass : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string anotherName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<ThirdClass> third { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (third.Any(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.foo3)
                        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.four?.foo4)
                        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.four?.bar4)))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid");
        }

    }
}
```

Refer this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fluentvalidation) if you wanna user FluentValidation